# The name of a property

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two linear spaces. Suppose the functional $L: X\rightarrow Y$ has the following property:

\begin{equation*}
L\left(ax+bx'\right)=aL\left(x\right)+bL\left(x'\right)
\end{equation*} for all $x, x' \in X$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}_+$.
Since $a, b \in \mathbb{R}_+$ rather than $\mathbb{R}$, this is weaker than linearity. I was wondering whether this is an established property with a generally recognized name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not weaker than linearity, since
$$
L(-a \cdot x -b \cdot x') = L(a \cdot -x + b \cdot -x') = a L(-x) + bL(-x')\\ = a \cdot -L(x) + b \cdot -L(x') = -a \cdot L(x) - b \cdot L(x').
$$
Here we use, among other things, that $L(x) + L(-x) = L(x - x) = L(0) = 0$, so $L(-x) = -L(x)$.

Notation may be a bit confusing, but the point is, you can absorb the minus sign into the vectors and argue with the vector space axioms that linearity holds for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R},$ using that it holds for positive $a,b.$